# iOS Android and windows Push notification

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an application for for iOS, Android and Windows mobile.I want to send notifications to  the application. AFAIK as someone new to this, I think that I need to send the notifications from my server to GCM server for Android and APNS for iphone, I have no idea for windows.

I was hoping if I can send the notifications directly to the phone (setting up a XMPP server , what the IM messenger usually use (JABBER,EJABBERD etc.)) without going to APNS of GCM .

EDIT : The application is an enterprise application so some customers don't want to share aur route their data across GCM or APNS servers.

Is that possible, please guide me to the same .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp, It's a pushnotification service library for Windows, IOS and Android

Comment: Thanks,so in this i don't need to send/route the notifications to Apple push notification server .. ?

As in this it says : `A server-side library for sending Push Notifications to iOS (iPhone/iPad APNS), Android (C2DM and GCM - Google Cloud Message), Windows Phone, Windows 8, Amazon, Blackberry, and (soon) FirefoxOS devices!`

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications for Windows Phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx

Or you can use a service like Parse.com that allows you to manage push notifications for all he platforms using one API.

Answer (score 0):

The library does that for you, you first need to do some configuration [Check here](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp).
Look a the samples.

Comment: Thanks Riv .. i came across `http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/building-an-aimicqjabber-client-on-ios-open-source-frameworks-examples-and-a-tutorial` can i use this to send push notifications .?